# how to select min, max and average with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to select the min, max and average value of the column VALUE and where the timestamp > some date and < some other date with LIMIT and offset

```
from sqlalchemy import func
...

engine = create_engine(URL)
metadata = MetaData()

my_table = Table(
    "my_table",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("value", Numeric()),
    Column("timestamp", DateTime(timezone=True)),
)

database = Database(DATABASE_URL)
metadata.create_all(engine)

query = my_table.select(func.min(my_table.c.value)).where(my_table.c.timestamp > some_date).where(my_table.c.timestamp < some_other_date).limit(100)
result = database.fetch_all(query=query)
```

But i get the following error:

```
aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

This is partially the generated query:

```
SELECT my_table.id, my_table.value, my_table.timestamp FROM my_table WHERE min(my_table.value)
```

One might think that the `min` would be used in the `select` statement and not in the where clause.

Looking on the internet people are using all kind of different ways with sessions and ORMs and raw queries with filers etc.

How do I create it with the above example?

Comment: `func.min(my_table.c.value)` What is `my_table.c`?

Comment: @JohnGordon welcome to the sqlalchemy world, in the examples of the docs they are using it to refer to the column...

Comment: my_table.c is analogous to my_table.column. It's a way to refer to one column in a table.

Comment: Really not sure about this one but you might want to try eliminating the my_table.select and just go with select. I think SQLAlchemy will infer the table from the func.min of your query. Perhaps that's throwing SQLAlchemy off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to [Table.select](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.select) is a where clause.  You have passed an aggregate function, and since aggregate functions are not permitted in `WHERE` clauses in SQL you get an error.

As [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558739/ben) suggests in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74764322/how-to-select-min-max-and-average-with-sqlalchemy/74764508#comment131950041_74764322), you would be better to use [sqlalchemy.select](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) like this:

```
query = sqlalchemy.select(func.min(my_table.c.value)).where(my_table.c.timestamp > some_date).where(my_table.c.timestamp < some_other_date).limit(100)
```

Comment: nice, ofc you have to use a list in the select and do some group by but other than that this works, cheers

Comment: No need for a list in the select in SQLA 1,4+.  You don't need a group by based on your initial query,